# How to add animation when i selected item in collection view

Tags: ios, animation, collections, uicollectionview

when i selected item in collection view i want 
[this type animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PlJr.jpg)

For the list, I think I can use UICollectionView, but the animation part seems to be tricky.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Your "animation" is a .png, a static image, so that's kinda hard to understand it. But it seems you want to add shadow (inner ?) to a cell. There are topic about adding a shadow.

Comment: I am not using any type .png or static image, and  thanks to giving idea about shadow, please if u have code for shadow(inner)

Comment: You can animate the transform property of `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: I was talking about the screenshot you posted. It's a .png. Not a .gif animated or a video. So there is no animation."please if u have code for shadow(inner)" I won't code for you. You can do yourself some research.